# Excel to SQL Server - server error

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access, export

I have a problem. I am trying to local export from excel to `.mdf` (SQL Server), and I keep getting this error:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).] SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

I searched different articles, and I tried everything. I installed again my SQL Server, but it still doesn't work. I checked Configuration Manager, but everything looks fine. Does anyane have any idea what else can cause it?

Answer (score 0):

The error explains that you did not specify the right database name, or the right ODBC name, or if you did you did not specify the right user/pwd combination to get access. You would need to get into those details to find the solution.

Did you try to import Excel from MS-SQLserver, which requires no configuration, and has no authorisation limiations (unless hte excel file is encrypted)?

Comment: I don`t have to specify username or password, i use local server and  trusted connection. I don`t have a database. It asks me for the name of database i would like to create. so i don`t think that database name can be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for extra information. With this information it seems you did not create a database yet. This you have to do before any other action. You are not exporting to an SQL server, but to one specific database on that server.

Comment: When I try to export, it askes me if I want to use and existing database, or to create one. And I choose to create one, so it doesn`t ask me for database name. I tried now as you said, I created a new database and tried to export to existing database, but when i get to finish, still getting the same error..

Comment: @Flo: You need to use the database in your connection string; further information [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2013/)